# Docker port mapping with multiple apps

Tags: docker, mapping, port

I create a docker container with Nodejs. Then I start the node server on port 8080.

Also, I map port and everything works fine.

My question is, on my server I have a few more apps and websites that are working on port 8080. If I map that port to docker, will all that apps and websites be unreachable?

As I understand, if I map one port to docker, that port will only check on docker and not on localhost. What is a good solution to migrate part by part?

Comment: There is no reason why you can't map your apps to multiple ports on docker host.

Comment: So the app that is not in docker container but it is on port 80, it will still work fine?

Comment: by "not in docker container" do you mean "not in docker host"?

Comment: That's right. not in docker host.

Comment: if you want to connect different container hosts, you need to use overlay network
https://docs.docker.com/network/overlay/